# Azure Function Isolated Worker Process - HTTP Trigger firing but not running function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-http-trigger, dotnet-isolated

Using the http trigger outlined here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide

```
[Function("HttpFunction")]
        public static HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestData req,
            FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            var logger = executionContext.GetLogger("HttpFunction");
            logger.LogInformation("message logged");

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            response.WriteString("Welcome to .NET isolated worker !!");

            return response;
        }
```

I am able to trigger this using an http get however the function is then not subsequently run. What could be the blocking factor here?

[image: HttpFunction]
[image: HttpFunction trigger being called]

Comment: Please share the code as snippet instead of images.

Comment: You are using .NET 6 or  7?

Answer (score 0):

- Place a breakpoint in the `Function1.cs`.
- To run and execute the function, you need to open the URL - (ctrl+ click) on the URL.

[image]

- Run the above URL.

[image]

- Press `function key` + `f5`  ,Now you can see the function executed and messages are logged.

[image]

[image]